# Python Split files into multiple smaller files

Tags: python, file, split

Write a function named `file_split(filename, number_of_files)` that will split an input file into a number of output files.  The files should be split as evenly as possible.  When the file length is evenly divisible by the number of files to create (a 10-line file, split into 2 files, each output file should have 5 lines.   When the length is not evenly divisible all output files’ length must not have a difference greater than 1.  For example, a file of 10 lines, split in 3, would have output files of length 3, 3 and 4.

I have written my code but I can not figure out how to do the difference greater than 1 part, I need help modifying my code to include that part. (The code I have creates a new file for the last line if it is not an even multiple)

```
def get_line_counts(filename, number_of_files):
    try:
        my_file = open(filename, 'r')
    except IOError:
        print("File does not exist")
        return    
    input = my_file.read().split('\n')
    outputBase = 'lel'    
    total_lines = 0
    with open('myfile.txt') as infp:
        for line in infp:
            if line.strip():  
                total_lines +=1    
    base_size = total_lines // number_of_files    
    at = 1
    for lines in range(0, len(input), base_size):
        outputData = input[lines:lines+base_size]
        output = open(outputBase + str(at) + '.txt', 'w')
        output.write('\n'.join(outputData))
        output.close()
        at += 1
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to split file into number of output files in Python 3?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30572321/how-to-split-file-into-number-of-output-files-in-python-3)

Comment: *"Write a function..."*? Are we your slaves, that you can give us commands?

Comment: @Stefan Pochmann Did you read the next paragraph?

Comment: @Stefan Pochmann That was what the problem from the text stated, not how I worded it lol

Comment: Well then why didn't you say so or in **some** way mark it as a quote? The way it's written, I find it's poor style and etiquette, certainly not to "lol" about.

Comment: @Stefan Pochmann I just joined this website, wasnt sure how to format.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Round-robin works and is easy:

```
with open('myfile.txt') as infp:
    files = [open('%d.txt' % i, 'w') for i in range(number_of_files)]
    for i, line in enumerate(infp):
        files[i % number_of_files].write(line)
    for f in files:
        f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

**Untested**:

I'd use modular arithmetic

```
res = len(lines) % number_of_files
for lines in range(0, len(input), base_size):
    if at == len(input)+res+1:
        outputData = input[lines:-1]
    else: 
       ...
```

That is, just dump the remainder of the lines into the last file.

Comment: That's not what he wants, see zero323's comments

Comment: Thanks, not exactly what I needed but still helpful!

Answer (score 0):

from **future** import print_function

```
import boto3
import shutil
import os
import os.path
import urllib
import json
import urllib2
import subprocess
import linecache
import sys

s3client = boto3.client('s3')
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    try:
        for record in event['Records']:
            bucket = record['s3']['bucket']['name']
            key = record['s3']['object']['key']
            print(key)
            p = key.rsplit('/',1)
            keyfile =p[1]
            print("S Object: " + keyfile + " is a FILE")
            inpfilename = keyfile
            ou = inpfilename.split('.',1)
            outfilename = ou[0]
            print("inpfilename :" + inpfilename)
            body = s3client.get_object(
                                        Bucket=bucket,
                                        Key=key
                                        )["Body"].read().split('\n')

            lines_per_file = 3  # Lines on each small file
            created_files = 0  # Counting how many small files have been created
            op_rec=''     # Stores lines not yet written on a small file
            lines_counter = 0  # Same as len(lines)
            for line in body:  # Go throught the whole big file
                op_rec = op_rec + '\n' + line
                lines_counter += 1
                if lines_counter == lines_per_file:
                    idx = lines_per_file * (created_files + 1)
                    body_contents = str(op_rec)
                    file_name = "%s_%s.txt" %(outfilename, idx)
                    target_file = "folder-name/" + file_name
                    print(target_file)
                    s3client.put_object(ACL='public-read',ServerSideEncryption='AES256', Bucket='bucket-name',Key= target_file, Body=body_contents )
                    op_rec =''  # Reset variables
                    lines_counter = 0
                    created_files += 1  # One more small file has been created
            # After for-loop has finished
            if lines_counter:  # There are still some lines not written on a file?
                idx = lines_per_file * (created_files + 1)
                body_contents = str(op_rec)
                file_name = "%s_%s.txt" %(outfilename, idx)
                target_file = "folder-name/" + file_name
                print(target_file)
                s3client.put_object(ACL='public-read',ServerSideEncryption='AES256', Bucket='bucket-name',Key= target_file, Body=body_contents )
                created_files += 1

            print ('%s small files (with %s lines each) were created.' % (created_files,lines_per_file))


    except Exception as e:
           print(e)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this
https://github.com/roshanok/SplitAndCompile

```
--------------------------------------------------------------
Usage: SplitAndCombine.py [-h] [-i INPUT] [-s] [-n CHUNK] [-m]\n
optional arguments:
-h, --help            show this help message and exit
-i INPUT, --input INPUT
                    Provide the File that needs to be Split
-s, --split           To Split the File
-n CHUNK, --chunk CHUNK
                    [n]: No. of files to be created
                    [n]kb : Split the file in nKB size
                    [n]b : Split the file in nb size
                    [n]mb : Split the file in nmb size
                    [n]gb : Split the file in ngb size

-m, --merge           Merge the Files
```