# How to divide a file?

Tags: python, file

I tried to split the file to multiple chunk file by divide the total line of the text file equally. However, it does not split the size equally. Is there a way to divide the file to multiple equal chunks without write any incomplete lines to the files using Python 3.xx? For example, a 100mb text file will be divided in to 33mb, 33mb and 34mb.

Here is what I get so far:

```
chunk=3
my_file = 'file.txt'
NUM_OF_LINES=-(-(sum(1 for line in open(my_file)))//chunk)+1
print(NUM_OF_LINES)


sorting = True
hold_lines = []
with open(my_file,'r') as text_file:
    for row in text_file:
        hold_lines.append(row)
outer_count = 1
line_count = 0
while sorting:
    count = 0
    increment = (outer_count-1) * NUM_OF_LINES
    left = len(hold_lines) - increment
    file_name = "text.txt_" + str(outer_count * NUM_OF_LINES) + ".txt"
    hold_new_lines = []
    if left < NUM_OF_LINES:
        while count < left:
            hold_new_lines.append(hold_lines[line_count])
            count += 1
            line_count += 1
        sorting = False
    else:
        while count < NUM_OF_LINES:
            hold_new_lines.append(hold_lines[line_count])
            count += 1
            line_count += 1
    outer_count += 1
    with open(file_name,'w') as next_file:
        for row in hold_new_lines:
            next_file.write(row)
```

Comment: Please rewrite your question to be more clear, and use proper grammar. Can you provide a sample of the code you've written so far? Can you provide an example of your input, expected output, and current output, so that we can see what's going wrong? What do you mean by "without truncate the text line"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code attempt to equalize, as faithfully as possible, the size of subfiles (not the number of lines, the two criteria cannot be met simultaneously). I use some numpy tools for improve conciseness and reliability. [`np.searchsorted`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) find the line numbers where splits are done in original file.

```
import numpy as np,math
lines=[]
lengths=[]
n=6

with open('file.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        lines.append(line)
        lengths.append(len(line))

cumlengths = np.cumsum(lengths)
totalsize = cumlengths[-1]
chunksize = math.ceil(totalsize/n) # round to the next 
starts = np.searchsorted(cumlengths,range(0,(n+1)*chunksize,chunksize))  # places to split

for k in range(n):
    with open('out' + str(k+1) + '.txt','w') as f:
        s=slice(starts[k],starts[k+1])
        f.writelines(lines[s])
        print(np.sum(lengths[s])) # check the size
```

without external modules, `starts` can also be built  by  :

```
chuncksize = (sum(lengths)-1)//n+1
starts=[]
split=0
cumlength=0
for k,length in enumerate(lengths):
     cumlength += length
     if cumlength>=split:
         starts.append(k)
         split += chunksize  
starts.append(k+1)
```

Answer (score 1):

If maintaining sequential order of lines is not important, https://stackoverflow.com/a/30583482/783836 is a pretty straightforward solution.

Comment: Sequential order of lines is actually important, but thank you for your answer,